# Examples of thematic mapping web services built with FOSS GIS

Tags: web-service, open-source-gis, web-mapping

What are some current examples of web services serving thematic mapping based on free and open source software?  The thematic mapping could be in the form of choropleth or point layers.  It would be very interesting to see some good publicly accessible geo-information systems, with the emphasis as much on simple but well-implemented projects as on those that are technically accomplished.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice project from SEAI mapping [wind](http://maps.sei.ie/wind/) and [geothermal](http://maps.sei.ie/geothermal/) energy potential. Very neat example of using MapFish and OpenLayers.

Although not purely about maapping I like design of [EveryBlock](http://nyc.everyblock.com/streets/manhattan/5th-ave/173-178/#tallermap). As far as I know it is based on GeoDjango, OpenLayers and Mapnik. And it's [open source](http://code.google.com/p/ebcode/).

Answer (score 1):

Look at this site,[Thematic Mapping](http://thematicmapping.org/), maybe you'll find there something that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.waterandhealth.eu/ is a nice MapFish and/or GeoExt based site. I'm not sure what the server behind it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link with many FOSSGIS thematic mapping examples
most are online mapping apps, a few are standalone desktop applications

http://gallery.osgeo.org/

A good example is with Time Slider (forecast):
http://www.meteosmit.it/previsioni/map
(using openlayers and postgis with google maps api)

Answer (score 1):

A bit shameless self promotion: http://zadeh.ugent.be/rwanda
Built using [mapserver](http://mapserver.org) and [ka-map](http://ka-map.maptools.org)

Answer (score 0):

The Environmental Response Management Application for NOAA was built on FOSS systems, though it uses Google's data.

http://gomex.erma.noaa.gov/erma.html#x=-88.36381&y=28.73568&z=6&layers=5723+8668+8978+8992+9057

Comment: The background map data is from Google, but the layers on top are from all over the place.  They include USCG NAIS processed with libais and all sorts of other data.... http://vislab-ccom.unh.edu/~schwehr/papers/2011-schwehr-ushydro-dwh.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Some digital atlases created with [Geopublisher](http://en.geopublishing.org/Geopublisher), they can be burned on a CD and used offline: http://en.geopublishing.org/demo
2. A JSF2 WebGIS platform based on

   - Openlayers,
   - OL4JSF,
   - [AtlasStyler](http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler) for SLD,
   - Geoserver for WMS
   - [GSRCJ](http://code.google.com/p/gsrcj/) to configure [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org)
   - PostGIS/POstgreSQL for data storage.

No proprietary GIS software used for the creating and running of the platform.

The page is in German, so use this loooong permalink to see something..

http://www.keck-atlas.de/keck-atlas/indikatoren/?permalinkid=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.keck-atlas.de%2Fkeck%2Fkarten.xhtml%3Fa1%3Dag_u3_k1%2Famp%2Fa2%3Dg_bev%2Famp%2Fdiagrammart%3DBAR%2Famp%2Fjahr%3D2008%2Famp%2Fves%3D05%252C05314%252C02%252C11%2Famp%2Fbbox%3D422294.23267252%253B6099103.953447%253B1340399.72776878%253B1467590.9428126002&sms_ss=email&at_xt=4d5fd9e7a8286963%2C0